# Accessing my contacts from broken iPhone?

Tags: iphone, contacts

My iPhone 4 gave up its last hope and hasn't turned on in two weeks. I need to get my contacts, and it's not backed up. What do I do? Phone doesn't turn on, say it's charging but won't turn on. Left it plugged in for three days, still had red battery sign. I'm about to hook it up to a computer to find whether or not I can access its contents.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) To help you get good answers, can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/301497/edit) your question to explain what you've already tried (if anything) in order to fix this, otherwise you may get irrelevant answers from other users? Also, when you say *it's not backed up*, do you mean it's *never* been backed up, neither with iTunes or iCloud? Or do you mean something else? It may be worth you reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Check your iCloud account to see if your contacts were backed up. You can go to [www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com) and then sign in with your Apple ID and password. Once you are in, you'll be able to view contacts and see if they are backed up.

As for the iPhone and its battery/power issues, you'll need to visit an Apple Store and get a new battery to replace the current one. Keep in mind you may have to pay for it since its likely that you no longer have a warranty on it. That should at least fix the issue. Also since support is no longer provided for the iPhone 4, they can choose to opt out of repairing it if they can't order the parts from the repair depot.

***Make sure that when you charge your iPhone that you use the standard Apple charger that came with your iPhone. By using third-party chargers, they can create issues similiar to this one.